# Computing probability density function at a point, given the covariance matrix and mean

Tags: density-function, covariance-matrix, multivariate-normal-distribution

(Edited for clarity.)

Say I have the variance-covariance matrix $\mathbf{V}$ and mean $\mathbf{\mu}$ of a multivariate normal distribution. Given a sample, $\mathbf{s}$, can I compute/estimate the value of the probability density function at that sample?

I'm trying to determine how well a given sample "fits" the various distributions determined by some $\mathbf{V}_i$ and $\mathbf{\mu}_i$ in order to label the sample with $\underset{i \in 0, 1, ...}{\arg\max\,}{f(\mathbf{s}; \mathbf{V}_i, \mathbf{\mu}_i)}$.

Comment: For anyone else who comes with the same question: yes, there is an analytic form for the PDF of the multivariate normal, and it's fairly convenient; see, for example, the `scipy` docs [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.multivariate_normal.html)

Answer (score 2):

The mean vector and covariance are not sufficient to give the entire probability distribution, so this is a case where you have not prescribed enough information to yield a probability density/mass function, or a likelihood function.  If you were to prescribe a class of distributions parameterised by the mean and covariance matrix (e.g., the normal distribution) then that would be sufficient to give you a likelihood function.  For example, if you use the [normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution), the log-likelihood function is:

$$\ell_\mathbf{s}(\mathbf{V}) = - \frac{1}{2} \text{det}(\mathbf{V}) -\frac{1}{2} \mathbf{s}^\text{T} \mathbf{V}^{-1} \mathbf{s}
\quad \quad \quad
\text{for all } \mathbf{V} \in \mathcal{V},$$

where $\mathcal{V}$ is the set of real square positive-definite matrices of the required dimension.

Comment: In practice, I'm using the maximum-likelihood empirical covariance estimator to get $\mathrm{V}$ in the first place, so making that same assumption (multivariate Gaussian) here is no worse than making it in the first place, right?

Comment: You can't be using any kind of "maximum-likelihood" estimator unless you have a likelihood function -- what would you be maximising?  Thus, if you are using a procedure like this, there *must* be some specification (possibly implicit) of what the likelihood function actually is.  Most likely the procedure you are using is (implicitly) assuming a Gaussian distribution, but you should check this.

Comment: Maybe I'm not saying what I think I'm saying. I have some set of observations from which I'm computing the covariance matrix (from [`sklearn`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.covariance.EmpiricalCovariance.html)). This computes the covariance assuming a multivariate normal distribution, I think.

Comment: Further, I think I'm looking for a $\ell_\mathbf{V}(\mathbf{s})$, for lack of a better way to put it. Does that have the same form? The likelihood of the sample $\mathbf{s}$ given the mean, covariance matrix, and the assumption of multivariate normal distribution.

Comment: Okay, well in that case you can use the formula above.  (Note that I have omitted the constant term $-\tfrac{n}{2} \cdot \ln (2 \pi)$ from the function, where $k$ is the length of the vector $\mathbf{s}$.  The computer program you are using would probably include this term.)

Comment: Great. How does one interpret a likelihood value? (I know you said that the above is log-likelihood, but I don't see any logs -- is it implied that I should be considering the log of this quantity?)

Comment: Hi @Ben: thanks for taking the time to try and answer my question before. Now that I've clarified it, does this answer still hold?

Comment: @Linuxios: Unfortunately, what you've written now does not quite make sense.  Taking $\text{arg max}$ over the variable $i$ would mean that you are looking for the single data point with the highest sampling probability.  I presume that is not what you're trying to do.  Perhaps read about [maximum likelihood estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood_estimation) and then see if this is what you want to do.

Comment: $i$ is an index over various distributions; $\mathbf{s}$ remains fixed.

Comment: Okay, so what you have is a maximum likelihood problem then.

Comment: Where the candidate distributions are given, yes